# Ruby DataMapper: undefined method `include?'

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I am trying an example on the page http://ruby.about.com/od/sinatra/a/datamapper.htm. I copied the following code from the web site:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3:///tmp/test1.db")

class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :firstname, String
  property :lastname, String
  property :email, String, :key => true
end

p = Person.new
p.attributes = {
  :firstname => 'John',
  :lastname => 'Doe',
  :email => 'john.doe@email.com'
}
```

Running this code by `ruby test.rb`, I got an error message

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:335:in `block in attributes=': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:332:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:332:in `attributes='
    from test.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `DataMapper.auto_migrate!` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh thanks. That's it! If you make answer with it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the below code from [`dm-core / lib / dm-core / resource.rb`](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/resource.rb#L304-L327).

```
# Assign values to multiple attributes in one call (mass assignment)
#
# @param [Hash] attributes
#   names and values of attributes to assign
#
# @return [Hash]
#   names and values of attributes assigned
#
# @api public
def attributes=(attributes)
  model = self.model
  attributes.each do |name, value|
    case name
    when String, Symbol
      if model.allowed_writer_methods.include?(setter = "#{name}=")
        __send__(setter, value)
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "The attribute '#{name}' is not accessible in #{model}"
      end
    when Associations::Relationship, Property
      self.persistence_state = persistence_state.set(name, value)
    end
  end
end
```

[`allowed_writer_methods`](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/model.rb#L656) is a *reader*, which has not been set. There could be several reason for not to set the variable `@allowed_writer_methods` to *The list of writer methods that can be mass-assigned to in `#attributes=`*. Out of those reason, you might not run [`auto_migrate!`](http://datamapper.rubyforge.org/dm-core/DataMapper.html#auto_migrate%21-class_method) to *drops and recreates the repository upwards to match model definitions*. Thus run this method to see, if your code works or not.

Regarding the error, yes it came from the line `model.allowed_writer_methods.include?(setter = "#{name}=")`, as for the above said reason, `allowed_writer_methods` gives `nil` and `Nilclass#include?` method doesn't exist. That's the reason **(NoMethodError)** obvious.